# Using custom maven repo with AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, repository

Iam moving to AWS right now and my SpringBoot builds using a custom lib in a currently local mvn repo.

I moved the mvn lib to a repo on S3 bucket.

Now the EC2 server Maven needs to access this repo. Therefore it needs the user credentials of the S3 user on Maven-level.

On my machine I set this user on {user}/.m2/settings.xml.
But how do I set it for a EC2 server?
Or how to set it inside the pom.xml? (Even if its a bad practice)

Or do anyone know a better way anyway? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing question. CodeDeploy is a deployment service, not a server. I assume you're talking about EC2? If you're using CodeDeploy, it's just running scripts that you configure.

However, I think the easiest solution would be to set the [S3 bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) to restrict reads by IP address. That way, you just need to give your EC2 instances access.

It looks like others have written ways to set it up [here](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/09/07/maven-repository-amazon-s3.html), [here](https://blog.zestmoney.in/using-s3-as-maven-repository-4b96e8045ccf), and others.